# weird error with R when using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm doing some small calculations and i decided to fill the data inside a `data.table` since it's much faster than `data.frame` and `rbind`

so basically my code is something like that:

`df` is a `data.frame` used in the calculation but it's important what does it contain.

```
l=12000
dti = 1
dt = data.table(ni = 0, nj = 0, regerr = 0)
for (i in seq(1,12000,200)) {
    for (j in seq(1, 12000, 200)) {
        for (ind in 1:nrow(df)) {
            if( i+j >= l/2 ){
                df[ind,]$X =  df[ind,]$pos * 2
            } else {
                df[ind,]$X = df[ind,]$pos/l
            }
        }
        for (i in 1:100) { # 100 sample
            sample(df$X,nrow(df), replace=FALSE) 
            fit=lm(X ~ gx, df)   #linear regression calculation
            regerror=sum(residuals(fit)^2)

            print(paste(i,j,regerror))
            set(dt,dti,1L,as.double(i))             
            set(dt,dti,2L,as.double(j))             
            set(dt,dti,3L,regerror)             
            dti=dti+1

        }
     }
 }
```

The code prints the first few rounds of `print(paste(i,j,regerror))` and then it quits with this error:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x3ff00008, cause 'memory not mapped'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

***EDIT***

```
structure(list(ax = c(-0.0242214, 0.19770304, 0.01587302, -0.0374415, 
0.05079826, 0.12209738), gx = c(-0.3913043, -0.0242214, -0.4259067, 
-0.725, -0.0374415, 0.01587302), pos = c(11222, 13564, 16532, 
12543, 12534, 14354)), .Names = c("ax", "gx", "pos"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: @Arun the two i index where an error by me when writing the question, but basically the function calculate something inside this loop (where it's written i calculate something), then i shuffle it, apply a regression on the shuffled data then i save inside the data.table

Comment: If you want to supply [reproducible code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I think you may get an answer.  I'm sure that three for loops is not the most efficient technique for what you're doing.  As it stands, I can't quite follow what is going on in there without knowing what `df` is and knowing at least a little bit about what happens in your innermost for loop.

Comment: @Justin i've updated my question with the df dataframe and the code inside the inner most loop..

Answer (score 4):

Without meaning to sound rude, I think you may benefit from reading a few R tutorials before going forward.  This question is also very likely to be closed as too localized.  Also, `seg faults` are almost always a bug somewhere, but you can avoid a bunch of this headache by understanding what each piece of your code is doing. Since its Friday, lets walk through some of it:

```
if( i+j >= l/2 ){
   data[ind,]$X =  df[ind,]$pos * 2
}
else{
   data[ind,]$X = df[ind,]$pos/l
}
```

I'll assume `data` is meant to be `df` and go from there.  We're inside two loops of `i` and `j` that both go from 1 through 20000.  They will never sum to less than `1/2` so you will always execute the first statement.  Also, if you ever expected the `FALSE` case to occur, you would need `else` on the same line as your closing brace:

```
if (i + j >= 1/2) {
   df$X <- df$pos * 2
} else {
   df$X <- df$pos
}
```

R is vectorized so doing the above is the same as looping through every value and multiplying by 2.  I also removed the `/ 1` statement since it doesn't do anything.  This whole section can be moved outside of the loop. Since its a constant operation of adding a column `X` that is double the column `pos`.

Next, your loop where you do a fit:

```
for (i in 1:100) { # 100 sample
   sample(df$X,nrow(df), replace=FALSE) 
   fit=lm(X ~ gx, df)   #linear regression calculation
   regerror=sum(residuals(fit)^2)

   print(paste(i,j,regerror))
   set(dt,dti,1L,as.double(i))             
   set(dt,dti,2L,as.double(j))             
   set(dt,dti,3L,regerror)             
   dti=dti+1
}
```

Taking, `sample(df$X, nrow(df), replace=FALSE)` will only show you the new order.  It doesn't actual assign them.  Instead `df$X <- sample(df$X, nrow(df), replace=FALSE)`.

Now, It looks like you're going to assign into `dt` (which is a function much like `df` and should be avoided as a variable name) at row `dti` the result of this fit error as well as your indicies?  As far as I can tell, nothing depends on `i` or `j`.  Instead, you're going to perform a randomly ordered fit `60 * 60 * 100` times... If that is what you want to do, by all means go for it!  But instead do it in an efficient way:

```
df$X <- df$pos * 2
fit.fun <- function(n, dat) {
   jumble <- sample(nrow(dat))
   dat$X <- dat$X[jumble]
   sum(residuals(lm(X ~ gx, dat))^2)
}

sapply(1:10, fit.fun, dat=df)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but first of all the 1 that you are refering to is not `1 its l`, secondly this just a test script, the actual idea that i want to implement is more complicated and you cannot use the vecotrized thing ..because it include other functions that will assign the ` X to df ` and concerning the sampling, yes what you mentioned is what i want to do ..but my problem is that the 60 *60*100 are not being filled inside the `data.table` instead i'm getting the error that i've copied

Comment: I suggest you break your problem into manageable chunks, specifically the portion that causes your error.  Then work toward a minimal reproducible example that will still give the error and post that working example to a new question.  Using the code you provided, there is no seg fault, but instead an error in the `sample` line.